# Exercise on Injective and surjective functions

Tags: functions

Let $ A, B, C $ be non-empty sets and let $ f, g, h $ be functions such as u $ f: A \to B, g: B \to C $ and $ h: B \to C $. If $ f $ is injective and $ g \circ f = h \circ f $, then $ g = h $.

This is false, right? For this to be fulfilled, the $ f $ function has to be surjective, it is not enough to be injective, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, but you should provide an example. A simple one is with $A=\{0\}$, $B=C=\{1,2\}$. Define $f(0)=1$, $g(1)=1$, $g(2)=1$, $h(1)=1$ and $h(2)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not surjective, $g$ and $h$ could do whatever they feel like doing off the image of $A$ under $f$.